# Subtracting $\frac{(x+3)}{(x^2-1)} - \frac{(x-2)}{(x^2+2x+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

$\frac{(x+3)}{(x^2-1)} - \frac{(x-2)}{(x^2+2x+1)}$

To solve the problem I first dissembled the equation on the denominator
 $ \frac{(x+3)}{(x-1)*(x+1)} - \frac{(x-2)}{(x+1)^2}$

I multiplied the denominator together and to do this, I think I have to multiply the top part as well right? This is where i get confused, I forgot how to do this problem as its been a long time. How would i go on to solve this?

Comment: What does solving mean here for you? These are just terms. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: its my bad, i changed it to evaluate if that works out

Comment: @MATHASKER, evaluate doesn't work either

Comment: Oh I guess simplify would than

Comment: You should perform the following arithmetic $\frac{5}{6} - \frac{2}{9}$ and think about how it applies to your problem.

Comment: @MATHASKER is this the answer :- $\frac{3x + 5}{(x+1)^2(x-1)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{x+3}{(x-1)(x+1)} - \frac{x-2}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x+3)\color{red}{(x+1)}-(x-2)\color{red}{(x-1)}}{(x-1)(x+1)^2}$$

Comment: where does the (x+1) in the bottom left go?

Comment: I know that you have to multiply the both sides by the polynomial that side doesn't have, but where did the x+1 from the bottom go? shouldn't it be $$(x-1)(x+1)^3$$

Comment: Could you explain what happened to the (x+1) at the bottom of (x+3) when you multiplied them together?

Comment: @MATHASKER: $(x-1)(x+1)|(x-1)(x+1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2|(x-1)(x+1)^2$

Comment: I still don't understand where the (x+1) went?

Comment: $\frac 56 - \frac29=\frac{5\cdot \color{red}{3}-2\cdot \color{red}{2}} {18}$. Understand?

Comment: no? i understand that u took common for denominator but i dont understand for the (x+1)

Comment: Could be so

 $$ \frac{x+3}{(x-1)(x+1)} - \frac{x-2}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{(x+3)\color{red}{(x+1)^2}-(x-2)\color{red}{(x-1)(x+1)}}{(x-1)(x+1)^3}$$

but now we need more computing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40769/discussion-between-roman83-and-math-asker).

Answer (score 1):

$a=(x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1)$

$b=(x^2+2x+1)=(x+1)^2=(x+1)(x+1)$

So, we have:

$$\frac{(x+3)}{a}-\frac{(x-2)}{b}$$

$$\frac{b(x+3)-a(x-2)}{ab}$$

$ab=(x+1)^3(x-1)$

$b(x+3)=(x+3)(x+1)(x+1)$

$a(x-2)=(x-2)(x+1)(x-1)$

Then,

$$\frac{(x+3)(x+1){(x+1)}-(x-2){(x+1)}(x-1)}{{(x+1)^3}(x-1)}$$

$$\frac{{(x+1)}[(x+3)(x+1)-(x-2)(x-1)]}{{(x+1)^{3}}(x-1)}$$

$$\frac{(x+3)(x+1)-(x-2)(x-1)}{(x+1)^2(x-1)}$$

Expanding:

$$\frac{7x+1}{x^3+x^2-x-1}$$

Comment: O Taubateano mereceu

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here and simplify the problem.

$$\frac{(x+3)}{(x-1)(x+1)} - \frac{(x-2)}{(x+1)(x+1)}$$

I'm going to call $(x+1)=a$ and $(x-1)=b$

$$\frac{(x+3)}{(b)(a)} - \frac{(x-2)}{(a)(a)}$$

So, on the right side we have (a)(a) in the denominator, and only one in the denominator on the right. So we have to multiply the term on the right by $\frac{a}{a}$.

The term on the left has (b) in the denominator, while the one on the right doesn't. So we're going to to multiply the one on the right by $\frac{b}{b}$.

Let's take those steps, and we get:

$$\frac{(x+3)(a)}{(b)(a)(a)} - \frac{(x-2)(b)}{(a)(a)(b)}$$

See how both denominators are identical!? Great! Now we can put both of the numerators on top of the denominator we worked so hard to get.

$$\frac{(x+3)(a)-(x-2)(b)}{(b)(a)(a)}$$

Now all you have to do is plug back in $a=(x+1)$ and $b=(x-1)$, open up the brackets and collect like terms.

Answer (score 0):

The common factor can be taken to front as coefficient in the numerator as well as in the denominator.

$$ \frac{x+3}{(x-1)(x+1)} - \frac{x-2}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)} \cdot [\frac{x+3}{(x-1)} - \frac{x-2}{(x+1)}] $$

$$=\frac{1}{(x+1)} \cdot \frac{(x^2+4 x+ 3) - (x^2- 3 x + 2)}  {(x^2-1)} $$

$$=\frac{1}{(x+1)}  \frac{(7 x + 1)}  {(x^2-1)}. $$